# C++ map template argument is invalid

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stdmap, invalid-argument

I am trying to create a map for which the value is a class I have defined in another file; namely, `FoodItemLookup`. However, C++ is giving me the error:

> template argument 1 is invalid

I find this odd, because I'm not using any templates.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong. I don't think I'm allowed to post all of the code, but here are the snippets in question:

The attempt at making a map:

```
std::map<string, FoodItemLookup> foodCatalogue;
```

A brief rundown of the FoodItemLookup.h file:

```
#ifndef FOODITEMLOOKUP
#define FOODITEMLOOKUP

#include <string>

class FoodItemLookup
{
  private:
  ...

  public:

  //constructor
  FoodItemLookup(std::string upc, int shelfLife, std::string name);

  //copy constructor
  FoodItemLookup(const FoodItemLookup &other);

  //destructor
  ~FoodItemLookup();

  ...
);

#endif
```

Comment: What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: You have not posted enough code for anyone to help you.  There are too many things we have to guess at, but nothing we can conclude.

Comment: If you don't do anything special before declaring the map, you would have to use `std::string` there, just like in the class declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should have `std::` in from of `string` in your first template argument:**

```
std::map<std::string, FoodItemLookup> foodCatalogue;
```

---

> "I find this odd, because I'm not using any templates."

Actually `std::map` uses templates. That's why you need to pass 2 types (here, `std::string` and `FoodItemLookup`) between the `<>` when instantiating your `std::map`.

[More information on templates.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm)

Comment: Oh... whoops. I thought something was wrong with my class. It’s always the little things. Thanks.